# Why does the blog page not take the page template selected?

Tags: templates, blog-page, blogroll

I have a page template called `post-list.php`.

This template lists all the posts that I have created with the title, date, author and an excerpt. Now, to list the posts I have created a page called Blog and selected this newly create template(post-list).

Now I head over to the reading setting and select the Posts page as Blog. But it seems to have picked the `index.php` as the template and not the newly created one.

What am I missing? Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Blog Page isn't an Page for Wordpress, but a Listing, and Takes the "index.php" if there is no "home.php".

How to Solve: create a home.php and Insert the code, that you need in there.